# Invalid Hook call on using material UI in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

when I tried to use matrial UI textfield I got the invalid hook call error. how to fix it ?

```js
import './Login.css';
import TextField  from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const Login = () => {
    return(
        <div className="login">
            <div className="loginContainer">
               //***** <TextField /> *****//
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Login;
```

When I remove the TextField Component it works fine. when I add it it says

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

I have the react and react-dom same versions
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2"

but still I got the error, can anyone give me the reason why it is so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have react and react-dom versions 17.0.2 in package.json before
Then I changed it to

{
"@material-ui/core": "latest",
"react": "latest",
"react-dom": "latest"
}

and then I executed the "npm install"  It installed the latest versions of all the dependencies mentioned above. This fixed the issue.